# How to "Show/Hide" Bootstrap 3 content after scrolling Up/Down on Mobile device?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a HTML element that would display two Call to Action buttons, on Mobile Devices only. One button is Call us and other is Quote button.

The current code will display the bar, however because I already have the phone number on the top of the page, I would like to display this Call to Action bar once the user begins to scroll down the page.

Unfortunately I'm not skilled with jQuery to be able to resolve this. And I'm pretty sure it's simple, but I don't know the correct terminology that would point me to proper Stackoverflow posts by others that have similar ideas.

```
<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom text-center hidden-lg hidden-md footer-nav" style="background-color:#0091EA;padding:6px;box-shadow:0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
           <button style="padding:10px 20px;font-weight:bold;border-radius:5px;" class="btn btn-default btn-md hidden-sm hidden-lg trackPhone pull-left" onclick="window.location='tel:xxxxxxxxx'"><i class="fal fa-phone-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;xxx-xxx-xxxx</button>

           <button style="padding:10px 20px;font-weight:bold;border-radius:5px;" class="btn btn-success btn-md hidden-sm hidden-lg pull-right" onclick="window.location='quote'"><i class="fal fa-piggy-bank"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Get a Quote</button>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit. Here is a working jQuery code for anyone who run's into the same problem or wants to do the same concept for mobile. Big thanks to @Tim Gerhard for help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).on("load", function () {
         $(".footer-nav").css("display","none");
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800){
           $(".footer-nav").fadeIn('slow').show('fast');
        } else {
           $(".footer-nav").fadeOut('slow').hide('slow');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I didn't want to do all the work for you but I think I made a small example for you that should lead you into the right direction.

You can use the `$(window).scroll(function(){})` to detect when someone is scrolling. With `$(window).scrollTop()` you get the current scroll offset. In my example I simply check if this offset is higher than one, if so, i show the button. otherwhise i hide it.

Now you could do all sorts of things with this example. You could add an animation, apply css.. whatever. I leave this up to you.

```
<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom text-center hidden-lg hidden-md footer-nav" style="background-color:#0091EA;padding:6px;box-shadow:0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
           <button style="padding:10px 20px;font-weight:bold;border-radius:5px;" class="btn btn-default btn-md hidden-sm hidden-lg trackPhone pull-left" onclick="window.location='tel:xxxxxxxxx'"><i class="fal fa-phone-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;xxx-xxx-xxxx</button>

           <button id="ctaButton" style="padding:10px 20px;font-weight:bold;border-radius:5px;" class="btn btn-success btn-md hidden-sm hidden-lg pull-right" onclick="window.location='quote'"><i class="fal fa-piggy-bank"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Get a Quote</button>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>

$(function() {
       $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1){
           $("#ctaButton").show();
        } else {
        $("#ctaButton").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I also made you a jsFiddle. Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/arw7z2k9/)

Comment: Thank you. It was a big help. Here is what I added and it works :) `$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).on("load", function () {
         $(".footer-nav").css("display","none");
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800){
           $(".footer-nav").fadeIn('slow').show('fast');
        } else {
           $(".footer-nav").fadeOut('slow').hide('slow');
        }
    });

});`

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)